# React converting class component to functional component with static error function

Tags: reactjs

im upgrading an old react pp to use functional components. I am having troubles with the error boundary class component . I simply dont understand how to update the `static getDerivedStateFromError` what is the correct syntax to update this function?

initial component

```
class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(_error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    sendError("ErrorBoundary", { info }, error);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <ErrorText />;
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}
```

New component, which is imssing something for sure as it never sets the error to true, which was done by the static function..

```
const ErrorBoundary = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  try {
    if (hasError) {
      return <ErrorText />;
    } else {
      return props.children;
    }
  } catch {
    sendError("ErrorBoundary", { info }, error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do the `componentDidCatch` nor the `getDerivedStateFromError` on hooks right now. Here's the documentation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#from-classes-to-hooks

> getSnapshotBeforeUpdate, componentDidCatch and getDerivedStateFromError: There are no Hook equivalents for these methods yet, but they will be added soon.

Comment: i read that as well... i guess ill have to leave the component alone then? I was hoping someone knew a workaround, so i can add that little check to my todos

Comment: Yeah, I would leave the component as a class component until they build those functionalities. It's not that a big deal tho